# How can I make Rmarkdown formatting of chunks comply with break lines?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

If I have a chunk like

```
niris <- iris %>%
  select(starts_with("Sepal"))
```

The `knitr` output of the chunk is

```
niris <- iris %>% select(starts_with("Sepal"))
```

But I would like it complies with the break lines of my code so it is printed in html as I print in code
. I was looking at R Markdown reference guide and at Yihui web and trying multiple options from Results and Code decoration and I couldn't get my goal.

Do you know how should I do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide a reproducible example, so I can only guess. You probably turned on the `tidy` option (i.e., you used the chunk option `tidy = TRUE`). If you did that, either set `tidy = FALSE` or just leave out `tidy = TRUE` since `tidy = FALSE` is the default.

Comment: Thank you! My Rmd files depend on a source file which I usually don't see and where it is set `tidy=TRUE`. And I didn't think trying the default option....